# How to run a command in cmd using c#

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a exe file in a folder and another .mobi file in the same folder.

I usually open cmd set the path to that folder and then type the command in cmd which will be "xyz.exe strip_source 123.mobi "

I need to do this automatically using c#.

I saw few post here but none of them say how to do this.

I tired using process.start but that just starts the cmd.exe.

Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: `Process.Start` is exactly how you would start an external process.  What did you try and how did it not work as expected?

Comment: Check the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Comment: Guys..Process.Start opens the cmd...that working and i have tried that before..But what i wanted to do is : 1. Open cmd 2.It should automatically set path to example this directory "E:\MPC\Test" which contiins a exe while which will run only through a cmd command. 3.After setting the path a command should be passed in cmd which is "xyz.exe strip_source 123.mobi "..I tried following many methods used in internet and was not successful and i'm new to c#..:) Please be kind :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process.Start is still the correct answer, you just have to set the parameters correctly.

Here are some very basic examples: http://www.dotnetperls.com/process

Comment: This worked : Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\Users\mohad\Desktop\Convert");
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "/C kindletool.exe strip_source 123.mobi";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);

Answer (score 2):

Did You try this ?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("your_path");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like the code below :

```
   //Create process
System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

//strCommand is path and file name of command to run
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = strCommand;

//strCommandParameters are parameters to pass to program
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = strCommandParameters;

pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

//Set output of program to be written to process output stream
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;   

//Optional
pProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = strWorkingDirectory;

//Start the process
pProcess.Start();

//Get program output
string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

//Wait for process to finish
pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Thanks guys...will try out the above steps n let u know the results

Comment: Guys..Process.Start opens the cmd...that working and i have tried that before..But what i wanted to do is : 1. Open cmd 2.It should automatically set path to example this directory "E:\MPC\Test" which contiins a exe while which will run only through a cmd command. 3.After setting the path a command should be passed in cmd which is "xyz.exe strip_source 123.mobi "..I tried following many methods used in internet and was not successful and i'm new to c#..:)